# jQuery if statement for 2 variables using val() and keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, keyup

So I am trying to create a script that will display certin message and the button after users inserts specific numbers into #ninja_forms_field_88. So basically, if the zipcode is 60515 display yes + button, if not display no and no button.

So I got it to work if the var is 1 to (yes) any other one (no)

Now, since this willbe a zipcode validator I need to makes sure I can insert more than one unique number - I've tried doing new Array [1,2,3]; but no success and to check it with zipCode == inputZip, I've tried using inArray but w/o success.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_88").keyup(function() {
    var zipCode = 1;
    var inputZip = jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_88").val();
        if (jQuery.inArray("zipCode") == inputZip) {
            jQuery("#yes").css("display", "block");
            jQuery("#no").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_90").css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#no").css("display", "block");
            jQuery("#yes").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_90").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the zip code to make sure its valid.  You can use a [regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to do this.

Something like this should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_88").keyup(function() {
    var zipCode = 1;
    var inputZip = jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_88").val();
        if (/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(inputZip)) {
            jQuery("#yes").html(inputZip);
            jQuery("#yes").css("display", "block");
            jQuery("#no").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_90").css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#no").css("display", "block");
            jQuery("#yes").css("display", "none");
            jQuery("#ninja_forms_field_90").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/vt1rgn21/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. So I just tested this and it shows me message NO, when I insert 1, or 2, or anything else?

Comment: Thats because 1 and 2 are not valid zip codes.  To be a valid zip code it must be 5 digits, the regular expression is enforcing that.

Comment: Oh, wow! nice. So, how can I test it with 2 zipcodes, ex. 60515, and 60004?

Comment: Where are the users entering zip codes?  Do they have two different form fields?  What are the ID's of those fields?

Comment: The users will enter zipcodes into: #ninja_forms_field_88. Just one field. So if they enter 60515 it will show yes, and the submit button, if no, then it will show no, and keep the submit button hidden: here is the url: http://goo.gl/gvajD5

Comment: I don't see the updated code on that link.  If you just wanted to check if two zip codes will show the button, you can see that at the JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/vt1rgn21/  Just type in 60515, and see the result, then clear it and type in 60004 and see the result.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I want the button and message to display if the zipcodes are 60004, or 60515 so if 60004=60004, or 6051=60515. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Yup, just add some jquery to change the html.  I updated the answer and the js fiddle with an example:  https://jsfiddle.net/vt1rgn21/1/

Comment: Wow, Adam! Dziekuje, thank you! So .html was the trick? This allows it to read whatever is in the input?

Comment: Shit, actually, I thought this will work and check against variables in the var zipCode. So basically, display the button and yes message if the inputZip == zipCode. I would add specific zip codes to the var zipCode = 60515, 60004, 60634. So if the zip code is 60004, or 60634, or 60515 ONLY then display the yes and button.

Comment: Wait... so you only want to check if the text entered is one of the 3 zipcodes, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vt1rgn21/12/  ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a few syntax errors with the jQuery functions, in terms of your array and assumption it would output a boolean. You can also minimize a lot of your code. Lastly here is a working fiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/Zachary1748/77h44jne/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#ninja_forms_field_88").keyup(function() {
        var zipCode = ["1", "2", "3"];
        var inputZip = $("#ninja_forms_field_88").val();

        if ($.inArray(inputZip, zipCode) !== -1) {
            $("#yes, #ninja_forms_field_90").show();
            $("#no").hide();
        } else {
            $("#no").show();
            $("#yes, #ninja_forms_field_90").hide();
        }
    });
});
```